# Prototypal inheritence - the correct way

Tags: javascript

I've been looking into doing inheritance in JavaScript the correct prototypal way, according to Douglas Crockford: http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html

He writes: "So instead of creating classes, you make prototype objects, and then use the object function to make new instances"

I figured this was the way to do it:

```
var objA = {
    func_a : function() {
        alert('A');
    }
};

var objB = Object.create(objA);
objB.func_a = function() {
   alert('B');
}
objB.func_b = function() {
};


var objA_instance1 = Object.create(objA);
var objA_instance2 = Object.create(objA);
var objB_instance1 = Object.create(objB);
var objB_instance2 = Object.create(objB);
etc...
```

But wouldn't this mean that there are now four instances of func_a (since it's isn't part of objA.prototype, it's just "inside" it), or am I not understanding this correctly?

Also, is there any way I can reach the overridden function of a function (for example call  objA.func_a inside objB.func_a)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing the `prototype` property of constructor functions with the internal *[[Prototype]]* property of objects, which is inaccessible (FF makes it available as `__proto__`); using `Object.create()` sets this internal property to its argument, so `objA` and `objB` will be the actual prototypes of your 'instance' objects, ie no function objects will be duplicated.

To call the overridden functions, access them via eg `objA.func_a` and use [call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/call) or [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/Apply) to use them on the specific instances, eg

```
objB.func_a = function() {
    objA.func_a.call(this); // call overridden method with current `this`
};
```

Comment: [[Prototype]] can be accessed by `Object.getPrototypeOf(object)` though it's ES5-only.

Answer (score 3):

There is only one instance of `func_a`, and it is defined on `objA`, that is because the Crockford's `Object.create` method uses that object (`objA`) simply as the prototype of your new objects:

```
console.log(objA_instance1.func_a == objA .func_a); // true
console.log(objA_instance2.func_a == objA .func_a); // true
```

`func_a` on your objA_instances are reached by the prototype chain, that objects don't really own that property:

```
console.log(objA_instance1.hasOwnProperty('func_a')); // false
console.log(objA_instance2.hasOwnProperty('func_a')); // false
```